# What's wrong with my code? I'm trying to get it to check through an array and tell me if there is any repeated numbers

Tags: java, arrays

```
boolean go( int[] array ) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++){
      if ((array[i] == array[j]) && (i != j)){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I was given just the boolean method and array, and told to make a method that will check the numbers in an array for repeating ( duplicate ) numbers.  Return true if none of the numbers in the array repeat.

Comment: return `false` should be outside the loop.

Comment: For one thing, your code won't compile.  It needs a return at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need return `false` only after the checking of all the items are done in the array.So, your `return false` should be outside the `for loop`. Also you don't need `&& (i != j)` condition as `i` will never be equal to `j` in this case.
Following code may help

```
boolean go(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: awesome! I see what I did now.. thanks! <3

Answer (score 0):

Here are several improvements.

- return false after finishing the outer loop.
- since `i` is always one ahead of `j`, you don't need the `(i != j)` test.

```
static boolean go(int[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
      for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
          if ((array[i] == array[j]) {
              return true;
          }
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And just for additional info, here is another way.

```
static boolean go(int[] array) {
       return array.length != Arrays.stream(array).distinct().count();
}
```

Comment: you have an extra `(` in the `if` statement. your code won't compile.

Comment: awesome! I see what I did now.. thanks! <3